# Vanilla JS version of jQuery document on click for links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addeventlistener

Is there a pure JS version of this?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  here.change(this);
});
```

The specific feature I'm looking for is adding event listeners for any link that's created later via JS (AJAX for example).

Comment: Since jQuery is completely written in JS, the answer is *"yes"*

Comment: What is expected result of `here.change(this)`?

Answer (score 21):

Modern browsers support `matches` which makes this a lot easier

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('a[href], a[href] *')) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('works fine')
  }
}, false);

document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><span>Click Me!</span></a><br /><div>not me!</div>';
```

You could make this more convenient with a simple function

```
function addEvent(parent, evt, selector, handler) {
    parent.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches(selector + ', ' + selector + ' *')) {
        handler.apply(event.target.closest(selector), arguments);
    }
  }, false);    
}
```

Note that `closest()` is only supported in the latest browsers, there's a polyfill on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

This replicates the jQuery behaviour a lot more, and is easier to use, it also sets the value of `this` correctly

```js
function addEvent(parent, evt, selector, handler) {
  parent.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches(selector + ', ' + selector + ' *')) {
      handler.apply(event.target.closest(selector), arguments);
    }
  }, false);
}

/* To be used as */

addEvent(document, 'click', 'a[href]', function(e) {
  console.log(this)
});

/* Add a dynamic element */

document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><span>Click Me!</span></a><br /><div>not me!</div>';
```

Comment: Only missing piece is sending the specific `<a>` element to whatever `here.change` is

Comment: @Phil - like that

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `closest`. Nice!

Comment: @Phil  We still do not know what expected result of `here.change(this)` is _"The specific feature I'm looking for is adding event listeners for any link that's created later via JS"_

Comment: @guest271314 why does it matter? OP just wants to pass the `<a>` element to it

Comment: @Phil `.change()` is a jQuery method. Simply passing `this` or `event.target` to a jQuery method would render moot the entire inquiry

Comment: @guest271314 `window.here = { change(elt) { elt.style.color = 'red' } }` <- not necessarily. We don't know what `here` is so it's pure speculation. In any case, it does not matter

Comment: @Phil Good point. Then not essential to be included as part of an Answer if OP's reference to `.change()` is not jQuery `.change()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `click` event to `document`. check if `event.target` `.tagName` is `"A"` and if `event.target` has property `.href`. It is not clear what expected result of `here.change(this)` is expected to do from text of Question

```js
function dynamicA() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "";
  a.textContent = "a";
  document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.target.tagName === "A" && event.target.href) {
    // do stuff
    dynamicA();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href>a</a>
```

Comment: To get a more `$`-like code, an alternative to prop checking is [`Element.matches(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this accomplishes what you want:

```
// for all dom elements on click
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var el = event.target; // get what is being clicked on
    if(el.hasAttribute('href') && el.tagName == 'a') { // check if it's a link
        event.preventDefault();
        here.change(this); // what is this?
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does code check if `event.target` is an `<a>` element?

Comment: Assuming the markup is `<a href=""><span>Click me</span></a>` this won't work, you have to account for nested elements and look for the closest parent element from the target matching the selector as well

Comment: `.tagName` should be all caps